# MATLAB coeffs function is not working as expected

Tags: matlab

Say my equation is

```
c2 - 2*c1 - 3*n + c1*n + 8*2^n*c3 - 2^n
```

when I do `coeffs(eq,n)`I get `[ c2 - 2*c1 + 8*2^n*c3 - 2^n, c1 - 3]`instead of `[ c2 - 2*c1 , 8*c3 - 1, c1 - 3]`

all I want to do is equate the coefficients to zero and get three equations like so

```
c2 - 2*c1 == 0
8*c3 - 1 == 0
c1 - 3 == 0
```

solve these three equations and substitute the values of c1,c2,c3 in another equation. How do I make coeffs work that way?

Here is my semi-functional code

```
eqn = v(1) * sym('y_(n+2)') + v(2) * sym('y_(n+1)') + v(3) * sym('y_(n)') - v(4);
eq = simplify(subs(eqn, [sym('y_(n+2)') , sym('y_(n+1)'),sym('y_(n)')],[y_n2,y_n1,y_n]))
c = simplify(coeffs(eq,n));
[c1 c2 c3] = solve(c(1),c(2),c(3),'c1,c2,c3');
ps = subs(y_n);
```

Here I am hardcoding that there will be three equations and three variables. How do I do it for a general case?

Comment: Do you maybe want n^2 instead of 2^n?

Comment: I want k^n where k is any constant

Comment: `coeffs` is used to find coefficients for polynomials. `k^n` is not a polynomial (at least not with respect to `n`).

Comment: I just want to equate the like terms to zero. How do I do that?

Comment: My question is duplicate of this question. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900283/grouping-like-terms-in-matlab